# autocomplete not working, no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Jquery's autocomplete is not working for me but I am not getting any errors. I have tested this code out on a blank page on my site and it has worked which leads me to believe something below is conflicting.

Javascript:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/candidates/search.json?name=" + request.term,
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
              term: request.term
          },
          success: function(data) {
              alert();
              response(data.data.map(function(value) {
                  return {
                      'label': value.FormattedName,
                      'id': value.id,
                      'value': value.FormattedName
                  };
              }));

          }
      });
  },
  minLength: 1,
  select: function(event, ui) {
      window.location.href = "/candidate/" + ui.item.id;
  }
});
```

Jquery Includes

```
<%@include file="body-scripts-start.jspf" %>
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery-appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery-easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/flot-tooltip/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>


<script src="assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>

<script src="assets/vendor/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/morris/morris.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/gauge/gauge.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/snap-svg/snap.svg.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/liquid-meter/liquid.meter.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/javascripts/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/jquery-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/jquery-datatables-bs3/assets/js/datatables.js"></script>
```

Contents of body-scripts-start.jspf

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>

<script src="/assets/vendor/jquery-browser-mobile/jquery.browser.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/nanoscroller/nanoscroller.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/pnotify/pnotify.custom.js"></script>

<script src="/assets/vendor/handlebars/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/momentjs/moment.min.js"></script>

<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/common.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vendor/sockjs/sockjs-0.3.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vendor/stompjs/stomp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/javascripts/notifications.js"></script>
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else facing a similar issue, I had two jQuery UI files being included in separate files that were both being loaded in the same file. This was overriding the newest one that had the method i needed.